# Travis-CI - add another task to the sbt command

Tags: scala, sbt, travis-ci

I read [this](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/scala/):

> By default, Travis CI will use
>
> `sbt ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION test`
>
> to run your test suite. This can be overridden as described in the [general build configuration](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/) guide.

But that link gives kilobytes and kilobytes of text that I don't grok.

In two sentences; how to make Travis CI use the following instead:

`sbt ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION test assembly`

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has to simply add a `script` section to `.travis.yml`, e.g.

```
language: scala

scala:
  - 2.11.5
  - 2.10.0

script:
  - sbt ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION test assembly
```

Comment: Find documentation for this [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Customizing-the-Build-Step).